# Floating sidebar with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write some code for a floating sidebar.
What that means is, when the sidebar `offset.top` value reaches a certain distance, it turns to `positon: fixed`.

I have created a jsFiddle with a demo, this is the full screen link: http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/Qcftp/show

And here is the link with the codes: http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/Qcftp/

So at the moment, things are working just fine. But I have made the footer really big (on purpose) and now, what I'm trying to do is calculate the `offset.bottom`. But for my surprise, there is no such thing.

How can I do that?

If you look at the demo you'll see that the sidebar overlaps the footer.

I need to remove `position: fixed` when it's getting close...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the sidebar to stop when it reaches the footer you can check if the current position of the sidebar + the height of the sidebar is greater than the top of the footer:

```
($("aside").position().top + $("aside").outerHeight() > $("footer").position().top) {
   // handle situation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"offset.bottom" is offset.top + [$(element).outerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/).